# Not a Fibonacci sequence

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

What is the next term in the sequence?

1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 18, 34, 60, 120, 214, 394, 788

hints:

#1

> "mapping" is a valid hint, but would probably confuse more than help

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

> Each term is the sum of the last $k$ terms, but $k$ varies as the sequence progresses. Values of $k$ are: $0,0,2,2,2,2,4,4,3,4,3,3,4$. I am yet to determine how these values are formed. The next term is probably the sum of the last 3 terms (1396) or the last 4 terms (1516).

Comment: This is exactly where I'm stuck too.

Comment: Ditto. Tried OEIS (both with and without the first two numbers) but no luck.